# Insert button in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to fix the code of an insert button. It's a button that inserts data into the database.

Here is my code :

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        SqlDataReader reader;

        sqlCon.Open();

        // string requete = "INSERT INTO [RECAP] VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "''" + textBox2.Text + "''" + comboBox2.SelectedValue + "''" + comboBox3.SelectedValue + "''" + textBox5.Text + "''" + textBox6.Text + "''" + Global.Global.GolbVar + "''" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "');";
        string requete = "INSERT INTO dbo.RECAP(code_reseau, tot_dcl, mont_debou, gch_dep, typ_port, mois, annee, emt_dep, utilisateur, date_maj) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', " + textBox5.Text + "," + textBox6.Text + "," + comboBox2.SelectedValue + "," + comboBox3.SelectedValue + "," +0+ "," +0+ "," +0+ "," + 0 + "," + 0 + ")";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(requete, sqlCon);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Ajouté !");
        sqlCon.Close();
}
```

Every time I try to run this it generates an exception that says

> Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: I believe your Values bracket syntax is where it went wrong. For example, `VALUES ('" + ` should be `VALUES ("'" + `

Comment: @KeyurPATEL you're not looking at the full code. Your suggestion is wrong.

Comment: @Fatima, `Console.WriteLine(requete);` and make sure your query looks like what you think it should. It's possible that something in one of your textboxes is causing this error. You should also probably include single quotes `'` around each value : `... + "', '" + ...`

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing

```
string requete = "INSERT INTO dbo.RECAP(code_reseau,tot_dcl,mont_debou,gch_dep,typ_port,mois, annee, emt_dep,utilisateur,date_maj) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', " + textBox5.Text + "," + textBox6.Text + "," + comboBox2.SelectedValue + "," + comboBox3.SelectedValue + "," +0+ "," +0+ "," +0+ "," + 0 + "," + 0 + ")";
```

with

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO RECAP (code_reseau, tot_dcl, mont_debou, gch_dep, typ_port,mois, annee, emt_dep, utilisateur, date_maj) VALUES(@txt1, @txt5, @txt6, ,@combo2, @combo3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)", sqlCon);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt1", textBox1.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt5", textBox5.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txt6", textBox6.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combo2", comboBox2.SelectedValue);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@combo3", comboBox3.SelectedValue);
```

and see if that works

Comment: actually it doesn't ...again an exception that says "ExecuteNonQuery: the Connection property has not been initialized."

Answer (score 0):

Check if the below

- textBox5.Text
- textBox6.Text
- comboBox2.SelectedValue
- comboBox3.SelectedValue

are all numeric type.

As they are not passed in single quotes, so either their values should be convertible to a number (and the respective column is also of that type) or they are causing the error as some text is inserted in the SQL statement without any quotes around it.